# Void pointer in C++

Tags: c++

I learned that templates are the `void*` equivalents in C++. Is this true?

I have this issue in polling "events" off some procedure, when I have an EventType variable and I may also need to pass raw data that is related to that event.

```
struct WindowEvent {
    enum Type {WINDOW_SIZE_CHANGE, USER_CLICK, ...};

    void* data;
};
```

The user may then cast `data` to the necessary type, depending on the event type.

Is this approach okay in C++? Are there any better approaches?

Comment: Yes, this is a good approach. There are more efficient versions like tagged pointers. Other worth considering is simply C++ polymorphism.

Comment: This is a terrible approach. Type safety

Comment: What kind of `raw data` do you need to pass with regards to the event being raised? Sometimes you do need to get 'dirty' with the C side of C++ and use a `void*` type, but C++ templates and polymorphism are powerful tools to utilize and with a little fore thought in your design you can usually come up with something that will eschew the need for `void*` to enable casting to different types ..

Answer (score 4):

In C, which generally lacks support for polymorphism, `void*` pointers can be used to accept data of any type, along with some run-time representation of the actual type, or just knowledge that the data will be casted back to the correct type.

In C++ and other languages with support for polymorphism one will generally instead use either **dynamic polymorphism** (classes with virtual functions) or **static polymorphism** (function overloads and templates).

The main difference is that the C approach yields dynamic (run time) manual type checking, while the C++ approaches yield mostly static (compile time) and fully automated type checking. This means less time spent on testing and hunting down silly easily preventable bugs. The cost is more verbose code, and that means that there's a code size offset somewhere, under which the C approach probably rules for productivity, and above which the C++ approaches rule.

Comment: Pray tell - How is writing a few more lines of code less productive than having to track down a defect when it is let lose in the field

Comment: What are the best alternatives?

Comment: @EdHeal: The cost of fixing a defect influences the code size at which it pays off to use a more strongly typed language. Many academics prefer to use languages like MatLab scripts or Python, and the field that their code is let loose on can be just a few other academics, or just themselves. I think they would not be half or even a fourth or eight as productive in C++.

Comment: C++ has a trade off with performance and type safety. Why not maximize the type safety of the language. There have been studies that the later that a defect is found the more expensive it is to correct (time/money/..)

Comment: @Pilpel: There are a multitude of C++ GUI frameworks, and they use a lot of different approaches to event handling. There's no way to say that any one is "best" without defining "best". But if you want type safety you should probably steer away from all the old "message maps" frameworks like MFC.

Comment: @EdHeal: Oh, there are lots of more type safe languages, including e.g. Ada, which has been used for the same kind of applications as C++. Also there are less type safe languages, including C, and e.g. MP/L-whatever, if that still exists (I used the x86 variant in the early 1980s), and including many scripting languages. This variety is Good™. Moving one language along that safety dimension (if I understand the "maximize the type safety of the language" correctly) just means that one changes the language's market niche, so to speak, with other languages stepping in in the vacated area.

Answer (score 0):

*"I learned that templates are the void* equivalents in C++. Is this true?"*

No - Templates maintain type safety

*"Is this approach okay in C++?"*

No

*"Are there any better approaches?"*

Depending on the use case one could use (for example)

```
class EventData {
   public:
      virtual int getData() = 0;
};
```

And then use the appropriate inherited class. Perhaps using smart pointers.

Comment: How would you use the returned `int`?

Comment: It is an example. Perhaps `getErrorCode` returns `int`, `getXCoord` returns a `point` type, etc...

Comment: Still, virtual functions serve little purpose there unless all events share them. You may want to include an example of a controlled down-cast for retrieving more event-specific data.

Comment: You take that into account with the getters.